# How to set index number as incrementing in a show/hide section

Tags: knockout.js

In my page, the data was bind using knockout. The li sections were hide/show by using conditions.

```
<ul>
    <li data-bind="visible: condition1()">
        <span> 1> Some Text</span>      
    </li>
    <li data-bind="visible: condition2()">
        <span> 2> Some Text</span>
    </li>
    <li data-bind="visible: condition3()">
        <span> 3> Some Text</span>
    </li>
    <li data-bind="visible: condition4()">
        <span> 4> Some Text</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In the span the index number will change depends on the condition. I need to number the index based on the visibility and in incrementing order.
I managed to solve this by using a variable which will increment in the conditions().

```
var modal = {
  data: ko.observable(null),
    indexNumber: 0,
    condition1: function() {
        ++indexNumber;
        return true;
    },
    condition2: function() {
        return false;
    },
    condition3: function() {
        ++indexNumber;
        return true;
    },
    condition4: function() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then changed the html as,

```
<ul>
    <li data-bind="visible: condition1()">
        <span> <!-- ko text: indexNumber --><!-- /ko -->> Some Text</span>      
    </li>
    <li data-bind="visible: condition2()">
        <span> <!-- ko text: indexNumber --><!-- /ko -->> Some Text</span>
    </li>
    <li data-bind="visible: condition3()">
        <span> <!-- ko text: indexNumber --><!-- /ko -->> Some Text</span>
    </li>
    <li data-bind="visible: condition4()">
        <span> <!-- ko text: indexNumber --><!-- /ko -->> Some Text</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now the issue is fixed, but is there any efficient solution to this problem? or is there any builtin property in ko for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might just want to use an ordered list:

**Edit:** for the styling/formatting of the list numbers, you can use css.

```js
ko.applyBindings({});
```

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: myCounter;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

li:before {
  content: counter(myCounter) "> ";
  counter-increment: myCounter;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ol>
    <li data-bind="visible: true">
        <span>Some Text</span>      
    </li>
    <li data-bind="visible: false">
        <span>Some Text</span>
    </li>
    <li data-bind="visible: true">
        <span>Some Text</span>
    </li>
    <li data-bind="visible: false">
        <span>Some Text</span>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: But I need the output as in format 1> Some Text 2> Some Text

Comment: You can do that with css. I've added some css to the snippet in my answer.